# How to program arduino due without arduino ide

Tags: arduino-due

Is it possible to program the Arduino Due without the Arduino IDE? Is there a standalone program that can be downloaded, and be used to upload a .bin file (which has already been generated from the arduino IDE) to the Due? Any guidance appreciated.

I read about SAM-BA programmer, downloaded it but double clicking the .exe file does nothing. Something seems to open but it disappers.

Answer (score 2):

The standalone program for most arduinos is avrdude: http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/

However, for the Due, it is [BOSSA](https://sourceforge.net/projects/b-o-s-s-a/):

> Unlike other Arduino boards which use avrdude for uploading, the Due
>   relies on [bossac](http://sourceforge.net/projects/b-o-s-s-a/). 
>    -- [Arduino Due Overview](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue)

Comment: thanks. Do you know if this one can upload the code via the native USB port? or does it need to have a jtag port?

Comment: It can use the USB port.  avrdude is the program the IDE uses to do its stuff.

Comment: Err… are you sure it's avrdude? The DUE features a SAMX ARM microprocessor, not an AVR.

Comment: I was wrong.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when on opening a program you get a console that pops on, it means that this program is meant for commandline usage and not CLI.

You should open a terminal, `cd` in the downloaded .exe directory, and then type that tool's name. You might want to try adding `--help` after the program's name to learn how to use it.

Another good idea is to look at what Arduino does by clicking on the verbose option in the preferences. Then you'll be able to copy/paste the command call and modify it to upload the firmware blob you want.

Finally, if you look up "AVR SAMX upload tool windows" on google you might find a GUI wrapper for the command line tool.